# Unable to lookup jndi name tomcat 8.0 mybatis

Tags: servlets, jndi, mybatis, tomcat8

I am using tomcat 8.0, mybatis 3.2.2, my application was working fine when I used datasource in mybatis-config.xml

```
<environments default="development">
<environment id="development">
  <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
     <dataSource type="POOLED">
    <property name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
    <property name="username" value="uid"/>
    <property name="password" value="pwd"/>
  </dataSource>
</environment>
```

I followed the procedure and solution given in many forums, particularly stachoverflow, but it didn't help. Here are the steps I followed. I have placed mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar under Tomcat8.0\lib and ojdbc6.jar under WEB-INF\lib folder. I am using java 1.8. Please help to identify where I missed

server.xml under Tomcat8.0\conf

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="jdbc/MYDB"
        auth=Container
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        username="uid"
        password="pwd"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
        />
```

Tomcat8.0\conf\context.xml

```
<Context>
   <ResourceLink name="jdbc/MYDB" global="jdbc/MYDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

web.xml within myapp/WebContent/WEB-INF/

```
<resource-ref>
   <description>DB Connection</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/MYDB</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

mybatis-config.xml with JNDI name reference

```
 <environments default="development">
<environment id="development">
  <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
   <dataSource type="JNDI">
    <property name="data_source" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/MYDB"/>
</dataSource>
</environment>
```

DBUtil.java has the below code

```
 String resource = "path of mybatis-config.xml";        
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream(resource);
        sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when I run the application(access the database), I get 
Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver.parseFabricURL(FabricMySQLDriver.java:97)

Please let me know where I have missed and whats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that you are using a MySQL JDBC driver for an Oracle database. This is an Oracle Driver: `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` and this is an oracle connection string: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE` but you mention this:

> I have placed mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar under Tomcat8.0\lib and ojdbc6.jar under WEB-INF\lib folder.

You need to place `ojdbc6.jar` (the JDBC driver for Oracle DB) under `Tomcat8.0\lib` and remove the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar` (a JDBC driver for MySQL DB).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thouh i didnt implement your solution , i can understand the issue. My deadline was too close,  so we chose Web logic server (since we had that flexibility to change the server) and I fixed the issue.